# Can any one tell me why my itemLIst array is not appended by value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
  // const item = 'mango';
  const itemList = [];
  const [item, updateItm] = useState();

  // listening to onChange of input.
  const listenInput = function (e) {
    // insert item to list
    updateItm(e.target.value);
  }

  const addItem = function() {
    let pv = item;
    itemList.push(pv);
    console.log(itemList);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='main-div'>
        <div className='center-div'>
          <h1>To Do</h1>
          <input
            onChange={listenInput}
            type='text'
            name='item'
            placeholder='Add item'
          />
          <button onClick={addItem}>+</button>
          <ol>
            <li>{item}</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

i need it to append the itemList with value of pv.
but every time i enter new value in input it replaces the older value.

**What i get**
`let say pv = 'mango'. then itemList = ['mango'] again when i set pv = 'apple' thn itemList = ['apple']`

**What i want**

`let say pv = 'mango'. then itemList = ['mango'] again when i set pv = 'apple' thn itemList = ['mango','apple']`

Comment: You set that list to an empty array on every render. Why not keep it in state? *(Although you may want to lift it up.)*

Answer (score 0):

i got it.
For every update by `useState` it re-render the `App()` function thus re initializing the `itemList` so every time i update item my `App()` reload and set `itemList` to `null`.